# Firebase init is not working with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Firebase init is not working on ubuntu 14.04.
This is the error i get everytime i try to execute this command.
Thank you for helping me.

> /usr/bin/env: node: no such file or directory

Comment: I don't know any specific answers, but it looks like an issue with node.js, no?

Comment: when i use nodejs filename.js it works with no probelms, i get this error only with firebase.

Comment: yes it was a node problem thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i finally found how to deal with it.
first of all it is a node problem, so i should remove it then just create a symlink of nodejs to node.

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge node
 sudo rm /usr/bin/node
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
 firebase init
```

and it works.